# Authenticate users with occupied values in realtime database on firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, xamarin

Hi I am a rather new developer to Xamarin Android.

Before this I am able to authenticate users with the SignInWithEmailAndPassword from Firebase. It is for my testing purpose.

But now, I already have details and values of users signed up through website(and saved on realtime database), so I cannot use the SignInWithEmailAndPassword function anymore since now I have to authenticate users with the values on database.

Can I authenticate users with the typical PutString("email", "value entered by users") and getStringExtra function? My guts say I can but if I start then I would change a lot of codes now. So I need some confirmation or any reading materials.

p/s I have searched everything and all tutorials or answers are directing me to save the details when user first sign up on mobile. The case is not like this. Web sign ups do not use the same database as phone. I retrieved the values in JSON file and import them to firebase. The web uses Hostinger's database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing database of user credentials and want to sign them in to Firebase Authentication, you'll want to look at [creating a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

In this process you:

1. Sign the users in with your own credentials.
2. Pass the fact those verified credentials and other user info to a trusted environment.
3. Use the Admin SDK (as shown in the link above) to mint a custom token for the user.
4. Pass that token back the client-side code.
5. Use the custom token to sign in to Firebase.

As you can see this is quite a bit more involved than your current approach with `SignInWithEmailAndPassword`, because the Firebase SDK actually takes care of most of these steps in that case.

Comment: Thank you! I'm now reading all those, kinda get the idea behind it!

Comment: Thank you! I have upvoted the answer. Im still new in posting questions. Appreciated your help!!